# How can I convert iTunes Gifts card to Bitcoin

Tags: exchanges

Hello I really want to know how to convert iTunes gift cards to cans or Bitcoin

Comment: Same way you convert them to dollars.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find someone (or some service) that wants to buy your gift card, and pay you in bitcoin. There is no way to just 'convert it' into bitcoin, per say.

Answer (score 0):

There are services for that. https://paxful.com is one that comes to mind.

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin stackexchange - please note that the [help/on-topic] explains why site or service recommendations are off-topic here.